# ¿Cómo hacer que QTextStream obtenga el valor de un QlineEdit en Qt creator?

Tags: c++, qt

Quiero hacer que una cadena entrada por el usuario en un [QLineEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html) se guarde en un txt, tengo hecho el código pero algo estoy haciendo mal, ya que al probar el txt esta vacío.
Probé esto mismo con el contenido de un [QComboBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html) y funciono, pero con [QLineEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html) no funciona.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked( ) {
  QFile file( "ARCHIVO.txt" );
  file.open( QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text );
  QApplication::processEvents( );

  QTextStream out( &file );
  QString b = ui->lineEdit_2->text( ); //aqui con ui.comboBox.currentText() funciona 
  out << b;
}
```

Comment: me falta una linea pero cuando estoy formalando la pregunta no me dja ponerla, seria out<<b;

Comment: En primer lugar no uses `QApplication::processEvents( );`, en segundo lugar siempre verifica si se abrio el archivo:  `if(!file.open( QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text );) return;` y por ultimo el archivo se generara en la carpeta donde esta tu ejecutable ¿Estas seguro de que el archivo .txt es el correcto? ¿Estas seguro que el `ui->lineEdit_2` es el QLineEdit correcto?, para ello te recomiendo imprimirlo con: `qDebug()<< b;`

Comment: Tal y como dice @eyllanesc, no necesitas `QApplication::processEvents( );`, comprueba siempre que el archivo se abre bien.
A mi el código me funciona perfectamente.
Añade `file.close()`, no dejes el fichero abierto.

Comment: @meegle84 no es necesario cerrarlo explicitamente ya que cuando  se destruye `file` tambien se cerrara el fichero